# Precise definition of jet energy scale and jet energy resolution

Tags: particle-physics, terminology, simulations, definition, large-hadron-collider

Is it correct to say that jet energy scale is only related to Monte Carlo simulations? I can't seem to find a pedagogical introduction about these things that states it properly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not actually a high-energy guy, and my knowledge of jets is all second hand, but I did do a graduate summer school on the topic one year. If I recall correctly...

- **Jet energy** is the total energy of particles making up the jet.
- **Jet energy resolution** is the experimental limit on how well that quantity can be known.

You'll note that both of these automatically depend on your jet identification scheme.

---

The reason you're not finding a lot of pedagogical material is that little of it is published. The state of the art in analysis moves fast, and any book will be obsolete with in months of hitting the shelves. None the less there are still a few. I used Perkins and Leo in grad school, but they are fairly dated by now.

Worse, the detailed meaning of these quantities can vary slightly from collaboration to collaboration. That is the algorithm used to compute the quantities is not set in stone, but exists as a nebulous set of expectations and practices, which each groups adapts to the details of the experiment. Exception: I believe that competing experiments at the same facility (i.e. CDF and D0 at the Tevatron or CMS and Atlas at LHC) collaborate to make sure that their definitions are comparable.

Comment: From my understanding JES is the correction one has to apply in order to go from the detector measured energy back to parton energy or at least to the energy of the stream of stable particles making up the jet before it reaches the detector (stable for detection purposes of course) while JER is basically what you said, but there is something in my lecture notes which doesn't add up properly and I was hoping for a more rigorous definition also involving MC simulations. Anyway you're all too right about this stuff being a « nebulous set of expectations and practices», thanks!

Comment: You are correct about jet energy scale. Basically, we have $E_\text{jet} = RE_\text{measured} + \Delta E$ where $R$ is the jet energy scale and $\Delta E$ is the resolution, i.e. a systematic bias plus some statistical noise. And you are also right that both are determined using Monte Carlo simulations of the detector. You must have a supervisor to ask questions to, I hope! There is no way you will get more than some qualitative answers without much operational power around here…